# Bind a buttons visibility in XAML to a viewmodel?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I want the button to be visible in `State.Away` and `State.Stop` but for some reason the button is always visible even if the `State` is different than `State.Away` and `State.Stop`.

**Xaml:**

```
<Button Text="Hello" IsVisible="{Binding View}"/>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private bool myBool;

public bool View
{
    get
    {
        if (State == State.Away || State == State.Gone)
        {
            myBool = true;
        }
        else
        {
            myBool = false;                   
        }
        return myBool;
    }
}
```

Comment: your VM needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise a PropertyChanged event when the value of View changes

Comment: Is the button invisible if you always return false? Then the binding probably doesn't know that "view" changed when "state"  changed.

Comment: Also, make sure the DataContext of the control is set to your ViewModel correctly

Comment: I would consider binding `IsVisible` directly to `State` using an `IValueConverter` that knows how to map the states to the visibility you want.  That way you don't have to worry about raising `PropertyChanged` on multiple properties, and you can get rid of `View` completely, simplifying your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924718/ivalueconverter-and-visibility

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `IValueConverter` from `State` to `Visibility`

```
public class StateToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is State)
        {
            State state = (State)value;
            switch (state)
            {
                case State.Away:
                case State.Gone:
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                default:
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return State.None; // your default state
    }
}
```

Then you bind your button to the converter

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StateToVisibilityConverter x:Key="StateToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Button Text="Hello" Visibility="{Binding Path=State, Converter={StaticResource StateToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: You may have to include some namespaces based on your existing code.  And if your real code doesn't match your example code exactly, he may have gotten some of the class names wrong.  But from a high level, this is all correct and complete.